# why is BnB coin selection algorithm not enabled by default?

Tags: coin-selection

BnB is one of the best coin selection algorithms existing and its implementation is in the Bitcoin source code. But as seen from this line: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/f72d80b07af8ecbb2f9df1e87344eb465186f19d/src/wallet/wallet.cpp#L2403 it is not enabled by default. Why is that or have I been mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the code. That variable tracks whether BnB *was* used. Not whether we attempt to use it.

BnB does not always yield an acceptable result, as it requires a solution with no change to exist. It is attempted, but if no such solution can be found, Bitcoin Core's coin selection falls back to other algorithms. The `bnb_used` variable remembers whether that was the case.